# Wordpress custom search url

Tags: urls, search, customization

I'm trying to chang my custom search url for SEO purpose. I found an article about how to change `mydomain.com/?s=query` to `mydomain.com/search/query`. However, i prefer to have a custom search url such as `mydomain.com/something/query`.

Is this achievable?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What article did you find to achieve that URL? please post a link and code. I would guess you can just change `search` to `something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy. Just add this hook for `template_redirect` action and it will redirect your search queries to nice url:

```
function wpse8170_search_url_redirect() {
    if ( is_search() && !empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/something/" . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse8170_search_url_redirect' );
```

Add to your `.htaccess` file:

```
# search redirect
# this will take anything in the query string, minus any extraneous values, and turn them into a clean working url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Why doesn't work it for me? I have custom search.php that I want to use.